# Form do not submit even when function is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I made the following code, but it prevents form submission in both cases.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#password_result_success').hide();
  $('#password_result_error').hide();
  $('#current_password_blank').hide();
  $('#confirm_new_password').blur(function(event) {
    data = $('#current_password').val();
    var len = data.length;
    if (len < 1) {
      //alert("Password cannot be blank");
      $('#current_password_blank').show();
      // Prevent form submission
      //event.preventDefault();
      $('form#form_change_password').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    } else {
      $('#current_password_blank').hide();
    }

    if ($('#new_password').val() != $('#confirm_new_password').val()) {
      //alert("Password and Confirm Password don't match");
      //$('#password_result').html('<i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i>');
      $('#password_result_success').hide();
      $('#password_result_error').show();
      // Prevent form submission
      $('form#form_change_password').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    } else {
      $('#password_result_error').hide();
      $('#password_result_success').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<hr>
<div class="container text-center">
  <h1>change password</h1>
  <form action="post.php" id="form_change_password">
    <div class="form-group">

      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="current_password" placeholder="current password">
    </div>
    <div id="current_password_blank" class="alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i>current password can't be blank </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="new_password">new password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="new_password" placeholder="New Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="confirm_new_password">confirm new password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirm_new_password" placeholder="Confirm New Password">
    </div>
    <div id="password_result_success" class="alert-success"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>&nbsp;password match</div>
    <div id="password_result_error" class="alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i>&nbsp;password do not match</div>
    <div class="text-center">
      <button type="submit" id="change_password" class="btn btn-default">Change Password</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

The complete validation I will make in PHP, but I would like to check via jQuery first, before making an AJAX call to PHP validation. The problem is that my script prevents the form submission even when it returns true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting your `submit` handler inside your `blur` handler, this means that any time that code is triggered a new handler will be set. It's not conditional execution, it will fire even when calling `submit` outside that block. You can inspect the bound listeners in your browser to check that once you hit that code, the listener remains after the execution.

You can rely on the [visibility](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/#visible1) of your validation containers to determine if you should prevent submission or not. You could also use other techniques, like adding a `has-error` class to your form or `data-*` attributes, but the idea remains the same.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Cache selectors to make them a bit shorter and more performant
  $pwd_success = $('#password_result_success').hide();
  $pwd_error = $('#password_result_error').hide();
  $pwd_blank = $('#current_password_blank').hide();

  $('#confirm_new_password').blur(function(event) {
    data = $('#current_password').val();
    var len = data.length;
    if (len < 1) {
      //alert("Password cannot be blank");
      $pwd_blank.show();
    } else {
      $pwd_blank.hide();
    }
    if ($('#new_password').val() != $('#confirm_new_password').val()) {
      $pwd_success.hide();
      $pwd_error.show();
    } else {
      $pwd_error.hide();
      $pwd_success.show();
    }
  });

  // Attach listener globally (and only once)
  $('form#form_change_password').submit(function(e) {
    if ($pwd_blank.is(':visible') || $pwd_error.is(':visible')) {
      // Prevent submission if there's an error
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<hr>
<div class="container text-center">
  <h1>change password</h1>
  <form action="post.php" id="form_change_password">
    <div class="form-group">

      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="current_password" placeholder="current password">
    </div>
    <div id="current_password_blank" class="alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i>current password can't be blank </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="new_password">new password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="new_password" placeholder="New Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="confirm_new_password">confirm new password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="confirm_new_password" placeholder="Confirm New Password">
    </div>
    <div id="password_result_success" class="alert-success"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>&nbsp;password match</div>
    <div id="password_result_error" class="alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i>&nbsp;password do not match</div>
    <div class="text-center">
      <button type="submit" id="change_password" class="btn btn-default">Change Password</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I changed the event from ''blur'' to ''keypress'' , am facing a problem using keypress event it shows the password match even when it does not

Comment: @OtávioBarreto Be aware that if you reload the form and just press 'Submit', it will! Because neither `blur` or `keypress` will fire. That's why setting an initial invalid state would be a good idea. Also, your handler is only attached to the `confirm_new_password` field, if you change `new_password` afterwards, the form will still be valid.